# Overriding form model instance field value in crispy forms

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I would like to put two forms for the same instance side-by-side, and render the second form using `UneditableField`s. It seems that a field like

```
UneditableField(
    "question",
    value="other value",
)
```

will render the form with the model instance's question attribute value, and not the value set in the `UneditableField`'s value parameter.

Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?